# Change color code of an element based on error status

Tags: javascript

I am sort of going crazy on this specific task. Basically, I have a status that gets updated based on some status. The status are ok, careful, danger. So if it is ok, then the color will be black. If there is any kind of error (i.e. careful), then it becomes blue. If it has remained blue for more than 2 minutes, it should become red and continues to be red until an ok status is provided. If at anytime the status is updated to ok, the minutes counter should be reset.

Now the challenge I am having is the update happens every second and for some reason, I just can't handle the 2 minute. Right now, it shows danger but then it turns to careful.

My code is:

```
   currentStatus = ''; // set by some other function
   previousStatus ='';
   displayedOn = 0;
   color ='black';
  function displayStatus() {

    const date = new Date();
    const now = date.getTime();

    switch (currentStatus) {
      case "ok":
      color ='black';

        if (this.previousSyncState == 'careful' || this.previousSyncState =='danger'){
          // previous status was an error of one kind so update
          // the last sync error reported then reset the timestamp
          localStorage.setItem('lastDate', date);
          displayedOn = now;
        }

        break;
      case "careful":
      case "danger":

        // has it been 30 minutes?

        var difference = now - displayedOn;
        var resultInMinutes = Math.round(difference / 60000);


        const minutesToWaitBeforeColorChange = 30;
        if (
         resultInMinutes >= minutesToWaitBeforeColorChange &&
          ["danger", "careful"].indexOf(previousStatus) > -1
        ) {
            // previously it was error and continueing to be same.
          displayedOn = now;
          this.isLateWarning = "red";
        } else {
            // it is either not 30 minutes on continue of an error
            // or previous it was ok
          this.isLateWarning = "blue";
        }

        break;
      default:
        this.isLateWarning = "black";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I follow, but I think you want to use `setTimeout` and a flag to indicate we're staying red until we get `ok`.

```
currentStatus = ''; // set by some other function
previousStatus ='';
displayedOn = 0;
color ='black';
// MY ADDITION - flag whether we're on a red-until-ok status.
redUntilOk = false;

function displayStatus() {
  const date = new Date();
  const now = date.getTime();

  switch (currentStatus) {
    case "ok":
      // MY ADDITION - reset the red-until-ok flag, if it's been set
      redUntilOk = false;
      color ='black';

      if (this.previousSyncState == 'careful' || this.previousSyncState =='danger'){
        // previous status was an error of one kind so update
        // the last sync error reported then reset the timestamp
        localStorage.setItem('lastDate', date);
        displayedOn = now;
      }

      break;
    case "careful":
    case "danger":

      // has it been 30 minutes?

      var difference = now - displayedOn;
      var resultInMinutes = Math.round(difference / 60000);


      const minutesToWaitBeforeColorChange = 30;
      if (
        resultInMinutes >= minutesToWaitBeforeColorChange &&
        ["danger", "careful"].indexOf(previousStatus) > -1
      ) {
        // previously it was error and continueing to be same.
        displayedOn = now;
        this.isLateWarning = "red";
      } 
      // MY ADDITION - don't reset to blue if the flag is on
      else if (!redUntilOk) {
        // it is either not 30 minutes on continue of an error
        // or previous it was ok
        this.isLateWarning = "blue";

        // MY ADDITION - set red in two minutes.
        setTimeout(() => { 
          this.isLateWarning = "red"; 
          redUntilOk = true;
        }, 2 * 60 * 1000);
      }

      break;
    default:
      // MY ADDITION - don't reset to black if the flag is on
      if (!redUntilOk) {
        this.isLateWarning = "black";
      }
  }
}
```